# A short paper on arXiv

Tags: arxiv

I have a short paper that I wish to upload to arXiv. 
It is about two pages, on mathematical application of previous construction (a math paper).

Actually, I intend to add to it another segment in the future.

Is there is a real possibility that it will be rejected because of its length?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not simply try it?

Comment: The only way arXiv weeds out bad papers is its "endorsement" system.  Length is not considered.

Comment: If you intend to add another segment to it, keep in mind though that many people tend to ignore updated revisions, since most of them just consists of minor corrections and the assorted copy edits made before publications. So if there is anything independently important in your additional segment, either finish it before uploading for the first time or consider splitting the whole thing into two separate papers, otherwise most people will miss it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there is a real possibility that it will be rejected because of its length?

**No: Length is irrelevant, quality counts.** A two page paper could be better than a twenty-two page paper.